# Function That Computes Sum of Squares of Numbers in List

Tags: python, list, function, integer

I'm trying to write a function sum_of_squares(xs) that computes the sum of the squares of the numbers in the list xs. For example, sum_of_squares([2, 3, 4]) should return 4+9+16 which is 29:

Here's what I tried:

```
import random

xs = []

#create three random numbers between 0 and 50

for i in range(3):
    xs.append(random.randint(0,50))

def sum_of_squares(xs):

#square the numbers in the list

    squared = i ** i

#add together the squared numbers

    sum_of_squares = squared + squared + squared

    return sum_of_squares

print (sum_of_squares(xs))
```

Right now this always prints

```
12
```

Because it's taking i as in the number of integers in the list as opposed to the value of the integer. How do I say "multiply the value by the value of the integer" for as many integers are in the list to get the squared values?

Asking that question led me to try this:

```
import random

xs = []

#create three random numbers between 0 and 50

for i in range(3):
    xs.append(random.randint(0,50))

def sum_of_squares(xs):

#square the numbers in the list

    for i in (xs):
        squared = i ** i

#add together the squared numbers

        sum_of_squares = squared + squared + squared

    return sum_of_squares

print (sum_of_squares(xs))
```

But it doesn't seem to be squaring the values of the integers correctly - I'm not sure what it's doing. See this screenshot [image: See Screenshot] of a [Visualize Python](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) walkthrough.

Comment: `squared = i ** i` is wrong. You either mean `i * i` or `i ** 2`. --- And is `i` even supposed to be visible from inside that function? It's a global integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing silly mistakes. try this:

```
import random
xs = []
for i in range(3):
    xs.append(random.randint(0,50))

def sum_of_squares(xs):
    sum_of_squares=0  #mistake 1 : initialize sum first. you are making new sum variable in loop everytime. 
    for i in (xs):
        squared = i * i  #mistake 2 : ** is exponent and not multiply.
        sum_of_squares += squared  #mistake 3
    return sum_of_squares

print (sum_of_squares(xs))
```

Comment: Why do we use sum_of_squares=0 to initialize sum? The second mistake makes sense and is easily fixed. Thanks.

Comment: what you were doing is declaring sum_of_squares inside loop so in each iteration it was declaring it fresh and calculating but what you need is total sum and not just the last iteration. plus mistake #3 was formula of addition below mistake #2.

Comment: so if we had [13, 31, 20] it would have returned the sum_of_squares as 400? Mistake #3 makes sense.

Comment: If you did it your way it would have returned 3*squared. and squared was i**i that is 20^20. so unexpected that would be.

Answer (score 7):

```
def sum_of_squares(xs):
    return sum(x * x for x in xs)
```

Comment: This solution is quite nice. I think it'll be harder for the asker to understand though.

Comment: agree w/ brandon. consider explaining in your answer why it's better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Right the concept first on paper.

1. You have List of numbers.
2. You have to parse the List, do the square and save it to some variable.

   ```
   import random

   xs = []

   #create three random numbers between 0 and 50

   for i in range(3):
       xs.append(random.randint(0,50))

   def sum_of_squares(xs):
       result = 0
       for i in xs:
           result += i*i

       return result
   ```